# Show path title on path

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to show the path title always on the path not while hover.

this is the example path code:

```html
<svg height="210" width="400">
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" title="theTitle" />
</svg>
```

I want to get `theTitle` and place it on the path, so how can I do this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking for?  Are you saying that you want the text `theTitle` to be rendered along the path you specify?

Comment: yes that's right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `title` tag by grouping it with paths you want to show it with.

```html
<svg height="210" width="400">
  <g>
    <title>First title</title>
    <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
  </g>
  <g>
    <title>Second title</title>
    <path d="M350 0 L175 400 L325 400 Z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: how? I can't understand what you want exactly. can you create a jsfiddle demo with divs I can peek at?

Comment: so you want selectable/copyable text like a tooltip?

Comment: you can try a tooltip library like tippyjs. here is an example for how can you approach https://codepen.io/dgknca/pen/wvJvwJw

Comment: If it doesn't meet your needs, you can ask another question by specifying your need more clearly. e.g. "how can I show such a tooltip on SVG paths using tippyjs?"

Answer (score 3):

You can use a normal `<title>`-tag for svg icons.

Here's the code:

```html
<svg height="210" width="400">
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"/>
  <title>Hello World!</title>
</svg>
```

Comment: @FatihCanIşık what exactly do you mean by that?